# Amplify UI Authenticator Component

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, authenticator

I'm using the Amplify ui Authenticator component for my react project signin page. Is there any way that page will be redirect to particular page (like Profile Setup) after first time login and signup only.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by changing the sign up email, with a link that redirects to the Profile Page, so that after the first log in, and after changing the password the user is immediately redirected to the profile page.